# Is it possible to copy remote settings from one configuration to another?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Using Unity remote setting is it possible to copy remote setting from development configuration to release? or just manually typing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A direct copy is not possible as far as i can find. But there is an export and import with CSV-file.

So just copy from one to the other.

[image]